# OSX bluetooth private network between 2 macs

Tags: macos, bluetooth, screen-sharing

Does anyone know how to create a private network over bluetooth that a couple of macs could use for screen sharing?  Our wifi router doesn't seem to like screen sharing (kicks us off after a few minutes and we need to get a new address - weird). We currently use firewire but would love a wireless solution.  Suggestions?  The docs on google are mostly about connecting to your phone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth is PAINFULLY SLOW… maybe 80-100 KB/s if you're lucky. It really isn't suitable for this sort of use.

Perhaps you could create a network on a host machine, and use a client mac to connect to it for screen sharing. An ethernet connection to the host machine would also allow for internet sharing to both macs (since you'd no longer be connected to your router.)

Comment: Sorry bud :P but i strongly recommend to avoid bluetooth whenever possible. Audio quality is horrible, data transfer speeds are brutal, and power consumption is a tragic.